# How to run Ubuntu as normal user and switch to admin to change environment variables

Tags: sudo, users, su

I've just started learning Linux at uni, and my first homework is to:

> change current user to admin, *do some stuff with environment variables*, switch back to normal user

I can normally log in under my account which is superuser, but the idea is to switch to SU, set an `env`-variable, and see that normal users can't access it (if my theory is correct). On the other hand I can log in as a guest, but neither `sudo` nor `su` commands work

```
sudo: Operation not permitted
su: Authentication failure
```

How do I create/become this "normal user" and complete the task?

Comment: add a user that doesn't have admin privileges and do it from that account. you will need to add the new user to sudoer group for sudo to work, but su should work.

Comment: Homework is off topic, sorry.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I humbly ask you to forgive me for being a smart being and specifying a little more details than "how to switch to superuser/work with root", when those questions are not the same as mine (sort of), and those old topics don't include the working solution.

Comment: Reviewing the [meta questions about homework](https://meta.askubuntu.com/search?q=homework+is%3Aq) I don't think it's justified to say that homework is off-topic. It's evident from the question that Alex F has already had a go at doing it, and is now *extending their research* to ask a question about it here, which seems pretty reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the shell you should do:

```
sudo su
```

and enter your password.
After that you can create a variable, for example like this:

```
export MY_ENV="some value"
```

You can check, if it was set successfully:

```
echo $MY_ENV
```

Please pay attention to the dollar sign. When you define an environment variable you don't use the dollar sign, only when you call it after that.

Now you can:

```
exit
```

Now you have switched to normal user mode. Try again:

```
echo $MY_ENV
```

and see what happens.